# Connecting C# application with CloudSql Database

Tags: c#, google-cloud-sql

I have an application built in C# as front-end that runs in various locations. I plan to create the Database in Google CloudSQL and connect that application so that all users can access the Cloud database.
Please help me out with `*connection string of C# Application with CloudSql*`.

Comment: Please tell what have you tried so far?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/json-api-dotnet-samples

Comment: The below is how I use to connect my database from server to C# application................................Now I am lost............ dunno how to connect to cloudsql........help me pls. if you can send me a .zip file of c# project that have connectivity to cloudsql

Comment: public static void Connect()
    {
        CONDB = new OleDbConnection("Provider=ORAOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=MBDATA;User Id=Scott;password=Tiger");     
        CONDB.Open();
    }

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to connect Google Cloud SQL with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52457709/how-to-connect-google-cloud-sql-with-c-sharp)