# How to connect Google Cloud SQL with C#

Tags: c#, mysql, database, google-cloud-sql

I just want to manage my database on Google Cloud using C#. I have just started learning database. P.S. I am not good at English. I hope you understand me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume you've already created your Google Cloud SQL MySQL instance.

Following the instructions at [Connect to your Cloud SQL instance using SSL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-ip#connect-ssl), you'll need to enable external SSL access and create a client certificate.

You'll download the three files: server-ca.pem, client-cert.pem, client-key.pem.

Install the [MySqlConnector](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/) NuGet package into your C# application.

Create your connection string as follows:

```
var csb = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder
{
    Server = "Google Cloud SQL IP address",
    UserID = "Your UserName",
    Password = "Your Password",
    Database = "Your Database/Schema Name",
    SslCert = @"C:\Path\To\client-cert.pem",
    SslKey = @"C:\Path\To\client-key.pem",
    SslCa = @"C:\Path\To\server-ca.pem",
    SslMode = MySqlSslMode.VerifyCA,
};

using var connection = new MySqlConnection(csb.ConnectionString);
connection.Open();
```

Note that for old versions of the MySqlConnector library, you will need to combine the SSL certificate and key into one PFX file. Following [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808669/convert-a-cert-pem-certificate-to-a-pfx-certificate), convert client-cert.pem and client-key.pem to a pfx file:

```
openssl pkcs12 -inkey client-key.pem -in client-cert.pem -export -out client.pfx
```

Then remove the `Ssl*` connection string options and add the following:

```cs
    CertificateFile = @"C:\Path\To\client.pfx",
    CACertificateFile = @"C:\Path\To\server-ca.pem",
```

Comment: Thank you so much !

Comment: How do i connect if there api is on Google Cloud, and not use ssl, do i just skip the
Certificate rows? @Bradley Grainger

Comment: If your application is hosted in Google Cloud, you may want to use the Cloud SQL Proxy: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-proxy

Comment: @BradleyGrainger if i were to use the connecting through public IP, thats mean i have to assign IP in the console every time a new user PC runs my C# app? is there any workaround where new user can connect to the google cloud sql more conveniently?

Comment: @John Exposing your database directly to end users is extremely dangerous. The typical approach for handling this is having a web service that authenticates client devices and performs database operations for users through an API.

Comment: @BradleyGrainger can google cloud sql database be used with c# desktop app? because i dont see c# language in the official doc

Comment: @John Yes, there is no problem connecting to a Google Cloud SQL instance from a C# desktop application or C# web API (running on Google App Engine, or running on a server you manage); I've successfully done all of those.