# How to connect to Cloud SQL using Xamarin (iOS project) on Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, xamarin, google-cloud-sql

I read the documentation on Cloud SQL [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app#unix-sockets) but in the solution explorer I not have appsettings.json file to put this code:

```
  {
  "CloudSQL" : {
     ConnectionString": "Host=127.0.0.1;Uid=DATABASE_USER;Pwd=PASSWORD;Database=DATABASE_NAME"
  }
}
```

Then, in your Startup.cs file, create a database connection:

```
var connectionString = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder(
    Configuration["CloudSql:ConnectionString"])
{
    // Connecting to a local proxy that does not support ssl.
    SslMode = MySqlSslMode.None,
};
DbConnection connection =
    new MySqlConnection(connectionString.ConnectionString);
```

I use empty blank project for iOS on Visual Studio on Mac. How to connect to Cloud SQL ?

Comment: You do not need to get the connection string from the configuration file.  You could hard code the connection string into the c# application but then if connection string changes you have to recompile.  Putting into the configuration file makes it easy to change without recompiling.

Comment: connecting directly to a db server from a client is generally a horrible idea and you should not do it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to connect Google Cloud SQL with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52457709/how-to-connect-google-cloud-sql-with-c-sharp)

Comment: Does my solution work for you? If yes, can you please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hard code the `connectionString` in code behind:

```
    var connectionString = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder("Host=127.0.0.1;Uid=DATABASE_USER;Pwd=PASSWORD;Database=DATABASE_NAME")
    {
        // Connecting to a local proxy that does not support ssl.
        SslMode = MySqlSslMode.None,
    };
    DbConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString.ConnectionString);
```

Well, it is not recommend to connect directly to a db server from a client. It's unsafe.